# Изменить названия фото

Tags: php, mysql

есть форма отображения картинки с меткой удалить ли картинку
и в поле   FORM[photo_rename] - указать новое имя файла картинки.

```
<div class="item_1">
        <label class="block title_1">Фото:</label>
        <?php if(file_exists(HOST.IMG_GALLERY_PATH.'/'.$obj->id.'.jpg')): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo IMG_GALLERY_PATH.'/'.$obj->id.'.jpg'; ?>" rel="example1"><img src="<?php echo IMG_GALLERY_PATH.'/_'.$obj->id.'.jpg'; ?>"></a>
            <?php echo general::link_to($tpl_folder.'/deletephoto/id/'.$obj->id,'Удалить фото?','onclick="return confirm(\'Вы уверены?\')"'); ?>
            <input type="text" name="FORM[photo_rename]" value='_<?php echo $obj->id.'.jpg';?>' class="input_1" id="pole">
        <?php else: ?>              
            <input type="file" name="file1" class="input_1">                
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

функция удаления

```
function deletephotoAction () {
    // сообщение
    $this>msg=general::messages(1,v::getI18n('backend_after_delete_photo'));
    // имя файла на удаление
    $_name= array (
        "_".$_GET['id'].'.jpg',
        $_GET['id'].'.jpg'
    );
    forms::delete_photo(HOST.IMG_GALLERY_PATH, $_name, 0);
    return self::newAction();

}
```

как сохранить новое имя которое вводим в поле для переименования?
сейчас вывел названия картинки

Comment: ничего не понял. Так вы что хотите? Удалить или переименовать? И как это всё связано?

Comment: переименовать фото которое уже загружено на сайт

Comment: а при чём тут удаление?

Comment: просто добавил как пример, как работает удаление

Comment: вот документация по перименованию - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rename.php